# Получение hash-а SHA256 многопоточно

Tags: c#, многопоточность, хеширование

Есть файл, файл делится на блоки (последовательности байтов).
Как многопоточно вычислить значение hash-функции SHA256 для каждого блока файла, используя Thread-ы?

Comment: Я не уверен, что это вообще в принципе возможно, т.к. хэш-функции в основном строят значение от последующего блока на основе предыдущего, и для построения конечного значения нужно последовательно прогнать весь поток данных через хэш-функцию.

Comment: Вам нужно вычислить хэши *только блоков* или хэш *всего файла* (с разбиением на блоки)?

Comment: ну так судя по задаче: разделить файл на блоки и получить хэш для каждого блока. Собственно получение хэша для блока и выносится в Thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала давайте напишем функцию для одного блока.

```
public static class Sha256Service
{
    private const long blockSize = 16384;

    public static byte[] CalculateHash(string filename, int blockIndex)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var hasher = new SHA256Managed())
        {
            stream.Seek(blockIndex * blockSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var buffer = new byte[blockSize];
            var actualLength = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            return hasher.ComputeHash(buffer, 0, actualLength);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь эту функцию надо вызывать параллельно для каждого блока в файле. Самостоятельно создавать `Thread` трудоёмко, я бы использовал PLINQ.

Количество блоков вычисляется по хитрой формуле которую каждый программист просто должен однажды заучить:

```
var blockCount = (fileSize + blockSize - 1)/blockSize;
```

Дописываем второй метод для параллельного вызова первого:

```
public static byte[][] Calculate(string filename)
{
    var blockCount = (int)((new FileInfo(filename).Length + blockSize)/blockSize);
    var result = new byte[blockCount][];

    Parallel.For(0, blockCount, (i) => result[i] = calculate(filename, i));

    return result;
}
```

Файл будет открыт для чтения в нескольких потоках. Это не представляет проблемы для RAID-массивов и твердотельных дисков, но, [насколько я узнал](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/multithreaded-file-io/220300055) на одиночных жёстких дисках производительность будет снижаться.

Если делать через `Thread`, то код начнёт выглядеть гораздо страшнее. Приблизительно так:

```
static byte[][] Calculate2(string filename)
{
    var blockCount = (int)((new FileInfo(filename).Length + blockSize) / blockSize);
    var result = new byte[blockCount][];
    var threads = new Thread[blockCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < blockCount; i++)
    {
        var i1 = i;
        threads[i] = new Thread(() => result[i1] = CalculateHash(filename, i1));
        threads[i].Start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < blockCount; i++)
        threads[i].Join();

    return result;
}
```

На что здесь нужно обратить внимание? Во-первых, на то, как хитро дублируется переменная `i` внутри первого цикла `for`. Это [известный паттерн для работы с переменными цикла внутри замыканий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264289/captured-closure-loop-variable-in-c-sharp-5-0). Страшно.

Во-вторых, у `Thread` нет метода `WaitAll`, приходится писать такой же почти вручную.

**ОТВЕТ НА ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ВОПРОС В КОММЕНТАРИИ**

Приведённый код мог бы обрабатывать и файлы, большие, чем ОЗУ, если бы не одно «но» — он создает поток на каждый блок, а у потока размер стека по умолчанию составляет 1 мегабайт.

Опять-таки, теория утверждает, что такое количество потоков не будут выполняться *и в самом деле параллельно* потому что потоков гораздо больше, чем ядер.

Задание тестовое, и я бы не стал заморачиваться, положив количество потоков равным 4 или 8. Тогда хеши блоков удобнее было бы считать большими кусками, состоящими из большого количества последовательных блоков. Делать можно было бы в 4 или 8 потоков. Метод `CalculateHash` стал бы сложнее:

```
public static void CalculateHash2(string filename, int inclusiveStartBlock, int exclusiveEndBlock, byte[][] hashes)
{
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (var hasher = new SHA256Managed())
    {
        stream.Seek(inclusiveStartBlock * blockSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        for (int i = inclusiveStartBlock; i < exclusiveEndBlock; i++)
        {
            var actualLength = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            hashes[i] = hasher.ComputeHash(buffer, 0, actualLength);
        }
    }
}
```

Метод `Calcualte` для 4-х потоков стал бы выглядеть так:

```
public static byte[][] Calculate3(string filename)
{
    var blockCount = (int)((new FileInfo(filename).Length + blockSize) / blockSize);
    var result = new byte[blockCount][];
    var thread1 = new Thread(() => CalculateHash2(filename, 0, blockCount/4, result));
    var thread2 = new Thread(() => CalculateHash2(filename, blockCount/4, blockCount/2, result));
    var thread3 = new Thread(() => CalculateHash2(filename, blockCount/2, 3*blockCount/4, result));
    var thread4 = new Thread(() => CalculateHash2(filename, 3*blockCount/4, blockCount, result));

    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();
    thread3.Start();
    thread4.Start();

    thread1.Join();
    thread2.Join();
    thread3.Join();
    thread4.Join();

    return result;
}
```

Считаем количество блоков, выделяем память под хеши, разбиваем все блоки на 4 почти равные части, и для блоков каждой части считаем хеши в 4-х разных потоках.

Вроде всё.

Comment: Вот мне именно через Thread-ы и нужно))
Почему Вы используете byte[][] , а не , например, string[] ?

Comment: Потому что встроенные в .NET классы типа `SHA256Managed` возвращают именно массив байт.

Comment: @Timon Дописал через `Thread`. Как и говорил, всё это плач и скрежет зубовный. Мучителям своим передайте, что будут и они собеседование проходить, и тогда закон всемирной справедливости может наконец сработать. :)

Comment: Спасибо, а как к этому всему прилепить условие обработки файлов, больших ОЗУ, это как-то возможно без сложных ухищрений?)

Comment: @Timon Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, теперь возникает исключение OutOfMemory, если пытать получить хэш файла как одного блока либо же если блок слишком большой

Comment: вот тут:
 var buffer = new byte[blockSize];

Comment: @Timon В коде таких блоков создаётся 4. Если не хватает памяти, значит, вы поставили большой размер блока.

Comment: я понимаю, а если мне и нужен большой размер блока? Это как-то можно обойти?

Comment: @Timon, можно, но код станет ещё сложнее. Я не готов на этот раз писать. Копайте в сторону `TransformBlock`/`TransformFinalBlock`.

Comment: C самого начала я ждал не кода, а подсказок, спасибо Вам большое за помощь! :)

Answer (score 7):

Если вам нужно посчитать просто хэши блоков, то нет ничего сложного: читаете по N байт из файла, скармливаете эти N байт алгоритму и получаете ответ. Каждый поток получает номер блока и читает байты от `N * i` до `max(N * (i + 1), file_length)`, где `i` -- номер блока, начинающийся с нуля.

Если же вам нужно вычислить хэш для *всего файла* поблочно, то используйте [hash tree](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTH) (русская статья содержит описание Tiger tree hash, использующего Tiger hash, но фактически [можно использовать](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree#Overview) другой алгоритм). Идея состоит в том, что для каждого блока вы вычисляете хэш, затем вычисляете хэши для каждой пары (или более) и так вверх по дереву, пока не получите единственный хэш. Этот алгоритм используется в P2P сетях для проверки целостности файлов.

Опишите подробнее, что именно вам нужно сделать и с чем возникли трудности, и я дополню ответ.

Comment: Мне нужно осуществить первый вариант, проблема именно в том, как это осуществить через Thread-ы, то есть использовать TPL, ThreadPool, BackgroundWorker нельзя.

Comment: @Timon Марк вам уже написал код, поэтому оставлю свой ответ сугубо теоретическим :).